# Appium Android Driver initialization failing - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I'm having trouble getting my android driver to work in Appium. I have:

```
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(SC_URL), caps);
```

Where SC_URL and caps have been defined.

I have linked all the jar files I thought I needed (Selenium 3.12, Appium, Java common lang, etc.) but I still have the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/DeploymentException
at io.appium.java_client.android.ListensToLogcatMessages.<clinit>(ListensToLogcatMessages.java:34)
at base.main(base.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

I have all of these at the top:

```
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.response.ValidatableResponse;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import static io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey.T;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName.C;
```

Any idea what I might be missing? Wasn't sure if it was a missing jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(SC_URL), caps);
```

to

```
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL(SC_URL), caps);
```

I don't think that that's the only problem you're encountering, but it's a start.

I believe the problem may be in your Java JRE in your build path.

Normally I would have posted this as a comment since I don't think it's necessarily an "answer" but it would be a very long comment.